# How to develop one contact form with tables but remove the tables for mobile devices?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have developed an contact form 7 form with tables in to put the column next to each other, it works great but on mobile it looks awful, does anyone know how I can remove the tables only for mobile ?

for instance, on pc I want the column to be next to each other, like it is and on mobile I want it to be underneath each other.

[Image of the contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdWyO.png)

here is my code as well,

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>


<label> Your Name        
  [text* your-name] </label> 
</td>
<td>
<label> Your Cellphone Number 
[text* your-cell] </label>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><label> Are you attending the wedding?</label>[select* ATTENDANCE include_blank "YES" "NO"]</td>

<td><label> Guests?</label>[select* Guests "0" "1"]</td>
</tr>
</table>



[submit "Send"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use divs instead of table cells, for the best flexibility. You can use media queries to change the width, styles, and even order of the divs depending on the users screen size. For example:

```
.mydiv {width:100%;}
@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .mydiv {width:50%);
}
```

But if you must use tables for some reason, you could use this two-column collapsing email design from MailChimp, which would also accomplish what you're looking for (but with a lot more code and a lot less flexibility...): https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/responsive-column-layouts/